# Turn off date comment in properties file

Tags: java

I'm writing `Properties` to a file like so:

```
final Properties props = new Properties();
final FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream("test.properties");
props.setProperty("name", "foo);
props.setProperty("age", "123");
props.store(fileStream, null);
```

Which works as expected but I also get a date comment at the top:

```
#Sat May 24 09:46:30 BST 2014
```

I can see where this is added from the `store0` method that gets called in `Properties`, but is there anyway I can turn it off?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184335/properties-store-suppress-timestamp-comment This seems to be a duplicate question, also sorry it doesn't seem possible