# How write data in properties file without writing date and time comments in java

Tags: java

I want to write data in properties file using java.I am able to write the data in file by using java,but i am getting comments like date and time everytime by default.

Please anyone suggest how to avoid or remove comments in the proeprties file using java

Here is my code:

```
File file = new File("C:/Software/app.properties");
Properties properties = new Properties();
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
properties.setProperty(""+data.split(Constants.DATA_SPLIT)[1]+"", value);
properties.store(fileOut, null);
fileOut.close();
```

My o/p is O/put is:

`#Wed Jun 04 13:23:54 IST 2014 CurrnerURL=J;SLDAJGLLASJGKPJ #Wed Jun 04 13:25:54 IST 2014 CurrnerURL=J;SLDAJGLLASJGKPJ`

I dont want comment session in file. Please suggest me.

Comment: Show us some of your code, then we can point out what's wrong.

Comment: Are you using log4j or something to write to properties file? Post the code please

Comment: possible duplicate of [Properties.store() - suppress timestamp comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184335/properties-store-suppress-timestamp-comment)

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible by default.

If you need this you must Override the methode store0 of `java.util.Properties`
Here  the part of the original class.

```
private void store0(BufferedWriter bw, String comments, boolean escUnicode)
         throws IOException
     {
         if (comments != null) {
             writeComments(bw, comments);
         }
         bw.write("#" + new Date().toString());
         bw.newLine();
         synchronized (this) {
             for (Enumeration e = keys(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
                 String key = (String)e.nextElement();
                 String val = (String)get(key);
                 key = saveConvert(key, true, escUnicode);
                 /* No need to escape embedded and trailing spaces for value, hence
                  * pass false to flag.
                  */
                 val = saveConvert(val, false, escUnicode);
                 bw.write(key + "=" + val);
                 bw.newLine();
             }
         }
         bw.flush();
     }
```

Comment: Using the Writer variant of the method using StringWriter and removing the first line before writing to the file (check for startsWith # if paranoid!), would be a relatively ok workaround if the file is not huge.